# ¿Cómo llamo un método en un sola clase usado el PDO de PHP correctamente?

Tags: php, php5, php7

Quiero realizar una sola consulta de una tabla **X**, usando el **PDO** de **PHP**, pero no logro entender muy bien la lógica del mismo para que dentro de una sola clase llame el método para hacer una consulta simple.

Anexo el ejemplo de lo que tengo:

```
<?php

class prueba{

    public static function conectar(){
        try{

            $cn= new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba","root","noscope");

            return $cn;

        }catch (PDOException $ex){

            die($ex->getMessege());

        }
    }




 function consulta(){

    $query = "SELECT * FROM prueba";

    prueba::conectar();

    $resultado = prueba::$cn->prepare($query);

    $resultado->execute();

        echo '<table>';
        while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$id = $row['id'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$nombre = $row['nombre'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$tipo = $row ['tipo'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$detalle = $row ['detalle'].'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }

        echo '</table>';

}

}


$prueba = new prueba();

$prueba->consulta();
?>
```

Y este es el error que me sale:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOException::getMessege() in C:\wamp64\www\Interruption\prueba.php:14 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp64\www\Interruption\prueba.php(26): prueba::conectar() #1 C:\wamp64\www\Interruption\prueba.php(52): prueba->consulta() #2 {main} thrown in C:\wamp64\www\Interruption\prueba.php on line 14
```

Honestamente no entiendo mucho de PDO  y como funciona mas allá de lo que es hacer la conexión. Agradezco su colaboración.

Comment: es `getMessage()` y no `getMessege()`

Comment: listo ya lo corregí, pero el error que tengo ahora es diferente

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Access to undeclared static property: prueba::$cn in C:\wamp64\www\Interruption\prueba.php:28 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp64\www\Interruption\prueba.php(52): prueba::consulta() #1 {main} thrown in C:\wamp64\www\Interruption\prueba.php on line 28

Comment: el _vector_  que me preguntastes: [Establece un atributo en el manejador de la base de datos](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.setattribute.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrigiendo los errores de sintaxis (string de conexión como dice Aldanux, getMessege) te falta considerar que el método estático `prueba::conectar` te devuelve la conexión. Luego debieras hacer:

```
$cn = prueba::conectar();

$resultado = $cn->prepare($query);
```

**EDIT** Estás imprimiendo mal el resultado. Dentro de tus `<td>` estás asignando variables en vez de imprimirlas. Debiera ser algo como:

```
echo '<table>';
    while ($row = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>id ='. $row['id'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>nombre ='. $row['nombre'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>tipo ='. $row ['tipo'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>detalle ='. $row ['detalle'].'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }

    echo '</table>';
```

Por cierto, esto te devuelve una nueva conexión cada vez que llamas a `prueba::conectar`. Sería mejor usar el patrón singleton para poner:

```
class prueba {
 private static $cn = null;

 public static function conectar(){
    if(self::$cn !== null ) {
      return self::$cn;
    }
    try{
       self::$cn= new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba","root","noscope");
       return self::$cn;

    } catch (PDOException $ex){
       die($ex->getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Retiro lo dicho.... Estoy muy distraído... De igual manera muchas gracias por tu aporte! :D

Comment: Estabas asignando variables en los <td> en vez de imprimirlas. Prueba con la corrección que puse

Comment: Si, jejeje perdoname, ya hice la correción, pero esas variables no son necesarias, pero tampoco eran la razón del por que no imprimian, es que tenía mal el nombre de la tabla, repito tu aporte es de mucha ayuda, MIL GRACIAS!

Answer (score 0):

Estas llamando mal al metodo, no debes referenciar a la clase, ya que estas dentro de esta, debes llamar al metodo de la siguiente manera:

```
$this->conectar();
```